# Test travis-ci script without commit on github

Tags: github, travis-ci

Always that I need to test some change on .travis file I need to push my commit to github, and if it fail, it is a problem, I would like to know, if there are any way to test my .travis file before commit it, preferably on travis-ci vm, it means I want to make the process that travis does when I push some commti to github, but without need to commit or push my changes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can run Travis-CI locally, in a docker image, in order to test your `travis-ci.yml` configuration file.

See "[How to Run TravisCI locally on Docker](https://medium.com/google-developers/how-to-run-travisci-locally-on-docker-822fc6b2db2e)": you can open a travis bash with:

```
docker run -it -u travis quay.io/travisci/travis-jvm /bin/bash
```

That article is about giving that local Travis instance access to your GitHub repo, but in your case, you can make a docker image (based on [one of the Travis-CI ones](https://gist.github.com/solarce/9642ed12f4fcc8d118a9)) which would mount the local repo folder you have on your machine, and will be able to do a `travis compile` in that mounted folder within the container.

If the test passes in your local Travis-CI, then you can push your local commits to your GitHub repo.